# HTML a link not working when linked to other pages on site

Tags: html

So i have a simple nav bar that links to other pages on the website.

```
<ul class="navbar__list">
    <li class="navbar__item"><a href="about" class="link link--dark">About</a></li>
    <li class="navbar__item"><a href="offerings" class="link link--dark">Offerings</a></li>
    <li class="navbar__item"><a href="testimonials" class="link link--dark">Testimonials</a></li>
    <li class="navbar__item"><a href="contact" class="link link--dark">Contact</a></li>
    <div class="navbar__contact">
      <a href="https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask" class="btn btn--dark">Book a session</a>
    </div>
  </ul>
```

Which all link to html files that also exist in the root directory (the same directory). Every time i try to use the link i am getting a response that says "Cannot GET /???" with ??? being the name of the html file i am trying to access.

I have played around with the paths, tried typing the name of the file explicitly, and have found that links to external sites work just fine, it's just internal pages that are causing problems.

The pages that i'm linking to do have content in them.

I'm hosting this locally using npm live-server, i'm not too experienced in it though and do wonder if there needs to be more configuration if i'm to use it to locally host several pages?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Typo: The files you are trying to link to, presumably, have `.html` on the end of the file name. If you want live-server to give you `about.html` then you have to ask it for `about.html` and not `about` which is a different URL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to write the full path to the file, not just its name

you missed `.html` after file name

If it is in the same directory, then write

```
href="about.html"
```